# measuring matrix distances within a python loop

Tags: python, function, loops, if-statement, matrix

I have the below code, which draws circles on a matrix by changing points from 0s to 1s:

```
def renderCircle(Nx,Ny,radius): #function for drawing circles at x,y with radius r
  x = np.round(radius*x_circ+Nx).astype(int)
  y = np.round(radius*y_circ+Ny).astype(int)
  for i in range(len(x)):
   if x[i]>0 and x[i]<1024 and y[i]>0 and y[i]<1024: #ensuring plotted points are within the grid
    S[x[i], y[i]] = 1
```

I then loop this function over different start points (`Nx` and `Ny`) and over a list of radii (multiple circles are plotted from each start point).
I need to add a section which will not plot the points from circle A if they are within any of the other circles - effectively an if statement which would say:

```
if x[i] and y[i] are outside r[all other circles]: 
   S[x[i], y[i]] = 1
```

Comment: I didn't get what your question is about what you have described.

Comment: @mkrieger1 the first portion code is a function. i then loop this function over a list of Nx and Ny coordinates, and over a list of different radii, producing  multiple concentric circles at each start point. what i am trying to do is add an if loop into the function so that a circles points won't be plotted within the radii any other circles

Comment: Okay, and what is the question? Was there a particular problem?

Comment: @mkrieger1 i am unsure how to return a list of all the circles that have been plotted when calling in the function in the first section of the code, and the write the necessary if statement